# Form to Email Contact Form

Tags: php, forms, email, send

Hi im having problems with my PHP code for sending an email via a contact form. The form used to work, but it stopped sending e-mails. I am new at php so please help.I am getting no errors and can see no problem with the code after researching it thoroughly, could someone help me??  Here is my code...

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "#@gmail.com";
    $email_subject = "##";


    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here   
        echo "<img src=\"../images/errors.found.png\"/>";
        echo "<br /><img src=\"../images/errors.below.png\"/><br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br />&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;               &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<a href='/home/form/contactform.htm'><img src=\"../images/back.png\"/></a>"; 
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['guests']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('');       
    }

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; //  required
    $guests = $_POST['guests']; //  required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

    $error_message = "";

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= '<img src="../images/fname.valid.png" width="744" height="26" /><br />';
  }
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= '<img src="../images/lname.valid.png" width="744" height="26" /><br />';
  }
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= '<img src="../images/email.vaild.png" width="744" height="26" /><br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[0-9 .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$telephone)) {
    $error_message .= '<img src="../images/phone.valid.png" width="744" height="26" /><br />';
  }  
    $string_exp = "/^[0-9 .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$guests)) {
    $error_message .= '<img src="../images/guests.valid.png" width="744" height="26" /><br />';
  }
  if(strlen($comments) < 0) {
    $error_message .= '<img src="../images/comments.valid.png" width="744" height="26" /><br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Number of guests: ".clean_string($guests)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

<!-- include your own success html here -->

<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><img src="../images/email_sent.gif" width="685" height="51" />
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Add "ini_set('display_errors', 'on');" before the mail function, remove the @ infront of the mail function and try again. Copy the message on screen and post here if still stuck.

Comment: Hey Robbie, thanks for your help, I have tried whatever you told me, it didn't dive me any error and didn't work without @ either. Could be anything else? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should get some message - otherwise we really don't have much to go on. Try changing the "\n" to "\r\n" in the message body (as some SMTP servers don't like that). Otherwise you need to search the email logs to see what happened to it - you'll need your host for that.